# Typescript function becoming undefined

Tags: typescript, next.js, undefined

The function binOp runs once when run from expression and then becomes undefined when it is called by term and I just can't figure out why it is happening. sorry for the amount of code but I don't know where to look anymore. Also it is running in a nextjs localhost if that makes an difference

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'binOp')

```
class Parser {
    tokens: Token[]
    tokIdx: number
    currentTok: Token

    constructor(tokens: Token[]) {
        this.tokens = tokens
        this.tokIdx = -1
        this.currentTok = new Token({type:"null"})
        this.advance()
    }

    advance() {
        this.tokIdx++
        if(this.tokIdx < this.tokens.length) {
            this.currentTok = this.tokens[this.tokIdx]
        }

        return this.currentTok
    }
    
    binOp(func:any, ops:string[]) {
        console.log("here")
        let left: any = func()

        while(this.currentTok.type == TT_MUL || this.currentTok.type == TT_DIV) {
            let opTok = this.currentTok
            this.advance()
            let right = func()
            left = new BinOpNode({leftNode:left, opTok:opTok, rightNode:right})
        }

        return left       
    }

    parse() {
        return this.expression()
    }
    
    factor() {
        let tok: Token = this.currentTok

        if(tok.type == TT_INT || tok.type == TT_FLOAT) {
            this.advance()
            return new NumberNode(tok)
        }
    }

    term() {
        return this.binOp(this.factor, [TT_MUL, TT_DIV])
    }

    expression() {
        return this.binOp(this.term, [TT_PLUS, TT_MINUS])
    }
}
```

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#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-dOAIstv1fxCAgXWXdITzeEIEPPBjzvWtpWvf97yA4Fn1fRtkJAr9cF-RDAOA1tbnbelGWZNkENgrkX2FLlsL-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-OiAJQSSuty16bXehCbVGr9NjshypsvRNwGTXaQB8i0znQHBaT1l6-q-O0PhIpTQ-RbRe0a5FSG52XefllaHXXfnSEoJAoCJLmDkZvUK7gYRuDhtilf6lXhrV9X3pNhrC0CisAMS-Zu41Y10S9zVyyLEPcve4cAfNmmlVT9OuSqaxbC5DxvFh-30SjmP4XjvA54VhfgyX48V+VGeN8oDR5B3uAzAUfffvBMC4sRkBkdRlkfcIC2XsuWFkVQgHCiOM1TEldkBcl1CgAA5O0JBXVYaKkDqAuc4ogA)

Comment: What do you mean "becomes undefined"? What exact error message do you get? And what line is that error attached to? And what code are you running when "it is called by term"?

Comment: I am told that binOp is undefined and cannot be read. it runs in this order; parse, expression, binOp, term. and when term is run it should go back to binOp but it has become undefined

Comment: "binOp is undefined"? Or object your are calling `binOp` on is `undefined`? Again, please edit your question and add the exact error message you are getting. My hunch is that you are misinterpreting an error message, but I can't know for sure since I don't know what the exact error is.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'binOp')

Comment: Surely an issue with incorrect `this` scope. Do you pass any of these methods as a callback to another function? Or, show us the code where you instantiate and use the `Parser` class.

Comment: let parser = new Parser(result.tokens)
          let ast = parser.parse()

Comment: thats all there is and the entire class is in the code above so you can see the entire this scope

Comment: How are you calling the `term()` method? Without a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this will be hard to debug. Please add one, perhaps [like this as a starting point](https://tsplay.dev/mLqR4W)

Comment: Make sure you're instantiating the class

Comment: i added a playground that is also getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'binOp')

This error does not mean `binOp` is `undefined`. It means the object that is supposed to have that method is `undefined`. This is a very important difference.

---

This line:

```
return this.binOp(this.term, [TT_PLUS, TT_MINUS])
```

Is not going to work. You can can't break off a class instances methods like this because the value of `this` is lost.

The value of `this` is set by how it's called. By default, when you call `myObj.method()` then `this` is set to `myObj` inside the `method` function.

All instances of a class share methods. So if you get a reference to method as a standalone function, there is no way to know what instance it came from. So `this` cannot be the `instance` that you expect.

---

So when you pass a method of class you either have to use an enclosing function:

```
return this.binOp(() => this.term(), [TT_PLUS, TT_MINUS])
```

Or bind the function before you pass it:

```
return this.binOp(this.term.bind(this), [TT_PLUS, TT_MINUS])
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#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-dOAIstv1fxCAgXWXdITzeEIEPPBjzvWtpWvf97yA4Fn1fRtkJAr9cF-RDAOA1tbnbelGWZNkENgrkX2FLlsL-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-OiAJQSSuty16bXehCbVGr9NjshypsvRNwGTXaQB8i0znQHBaT1l6-q-O0PhIpTQ-RbRe0a5FSG52XefllaHXXfnSEoJAoCJLmDkZvUK7gYRuDhtilf6lXhrV9X3pNhrC0CisAMS-Zu41Y10S9zVyyLEPcve4cAfNlkpuIAA+XbU-TucuSqaxbC5DxvFh-30SjmP4XjvA54VhfgyX48V8ldfdrAGed4gPfpDkeRD7gMwFAn1+uCMCcVEYgGRqjFkfcIC2XsuWFkVQYHCiOM1TEldkBcl1CgAA5O0HBXVYaKkDvAuc4ogA)

Comment: ah so does this mean that running it the first time from the expression function changed the instance meaning further ones wouldn't run?

Comment: just changed it and it works great! Thanks a lot for talking through the issue rather than just the solution

Comment: The first time `myInstance.parse()` calls `this.expression()` which calls `this.binOp()`. There is a `.` and a `()` in each of those exrpessions that sets the value of `this`. But then you pass `this.term` (without invoking it at that point) and later invoking with `func()`. That is when `this` is lost. So you need package the value of `this` with that `func()` somehow.